# Faild when I try to send an email in Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, configuration

I'm trying to send an email in Jenkins. I'm doing next steps:

1. Jenkins -> Configure System
2. In "E-mail Notification" area I'm providing next data, click "Test Configuration" and many errors appears:

   [image]

Could you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need gmail smtp server's certificate

Please try the following steps from http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2012/04/import-gmail-certificate-into-java.html (1)

Copied from the (1):
"

> The following procedures are to import the gmail smtp certificate into the default Java keystore (Depends on the java mail application, the location of keystore may be vary):

1. Connect to smtp.gmail.com:465 to display the certificate in a terminal window:
   For Linux:

   > openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
   >   For Mac OS:
   >   openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
   >   For Windows
   >   Install openssl first
2. Run command:

   > s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
3. Copy and save the lines between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" into a file, say, gmail.cert
4. Import the certificate into java keystore(Default location):

   > sudo keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore /path/to/keystore -file /Users/wilson/gmail.cert

   For Windows:

   > keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -file C:\Users\wilson\gmail.cert

   For Mac OS:

   > sudo keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework//Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/lib/security/cacerts -file /Users/wilson/gmail.cert

   For Linux:

   > sudo keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /Users/wilson/gmail.cert

Note: your need to provide the password to access the keystore. The password for the default java keystore is changeit

Answer Yes when it ask "Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes"

Note: if your java mail client application uses its own keystore, you need to change the location of the application's keystore rather than JVM's keystore in the keytool command.
"

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've done everything according to your steps. But there is an error appears after I've put this command into cmd:

keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre1.8.0_161/lib/security/cacerts" -file C:\Users\cheil\gmail.cert

Then I put password, and then I get: 

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Comment: Ok,I've added the certificate succesfully. But the function 'sending email' in Jenkins still not work.